# Pass value from boundfield of gridview to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 gridview look like this:
[image]
and 2 controller for those gridview:

Gridview Controller 1:

```
 [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public List<OutstandingOrderInfo> OrderInfo()
    {
        using (var context = new eToolsContext())
        {
            var data2 = from po in context.PurchaseOrders
                       where !po.Closed                         
                       select new OutstandingOrderInfo()
                       {
                           Order = po.PurchaseOrderID,
                           Date = po.OrderDate,
                           VendorName = po.Vendor.VendorName,
                           ContactPhone = po.Vendor.Phone
                       };
            return data2.ToList();
        }
    }
```

GridView2 Controller

```
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select,false)]
    public OrderDetail GetOrderDetail (int purchaseOrderID)
    {
        using (var context = new eToolsContext())
        {
            var data = from pod in context.PurchaseOrderDetails
                       where pod.PurchaseOrderID == purchaseOrderID
                       select new OrderDetail()
                       {

                           StockItemID = pod.StockItemID,
                           Description = pod.StockItem.Description,
                           QuantityOnOrder = pod.StockItem.QuantityOnOrder,

                       };
            return data.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to pass the value of Order boundfield in Gridview1 to controller of Gridview 2 as the parameter whenever the ViewOrder link button is clicked.
But I received the error that the data I passed is null. What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code for handling the click event:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true; // to prevent any other processing in the GridView's default Select handling

    GridView sendingGridView = sender as GridView; // notice the safe casting
    GridViewRow row = sendingGridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];


    var orderID = row.FindControl("Order") as Label;
    int puchaseOrderID = int.Parse(orderID.Text);

    GetOrderDetail(puchaseOrderID);


}

private void GetOrderDetail(int purchaseOrderID)
{
    var controller = new ReceivingController();
    var data = controller.GetOrderDetail(purchaseOrderID);
    GridView2.DataSource = data.OrderDetail;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```